Is there friendly fire in Halo Infinite multiplayer?
Like the title states:
I'd like to know if there is friendly fire in Halo Infinite multiplayer.
If I shoot or melee teammates, will they take damage? What about driving over them?
And is it the same for all multiplayer game modes? Is it the same for all weopons and abilities?

Friendly fire does exist, but only in Ranked Arena mode. Shooting and driving on your opponents will damage or kill them.
In unranked modes, it's deactivated for shooting, but getting damaged or killed by vehicles is still possible.
